# What's the default Google Maps API map size?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking to embed a Google Map on my website, but I would like to know what is the "best" map size to use so it does not repeat the tiles? Is there a specific dimension?

Comment: What do you mean by "map size" (a number of pixels?) and "repeat the tiles?"

Comment: The map won't get repeated, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, number of pixels. And by "repeat the tiles" I am referring to when you see continents more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps have 22 zoom levels, with 0 being the entire world.

1. Determine the size you want the map to be.  (I often use 500 x 500 in my designs, but it all depends on the site)
2. Set your zoom level to anything other than 0.  (if it's a section of a city, 12-14 is often good.)

In this way, the only way tiles will repeat is if the user zooms out too much.  Of course, you can also disable that control, too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your zoom level, not the map size. You can easily have a 100% width and height map without any repeating tiles.